# Using Flow to add lead to a campaign

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, leads, automation, campaign

We have leads coming in from various sources. Depending on the source of the lead, the lead should be attached to a specific campaign. How would we leverage process builder and flow to automate this without having 40+ different nodes in Process Builder criteria for each of the lead sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a PB would work as you would have to hard code the ids but a flow or pb that calls a flow should work.

1. Create a custom field on the campaign called **lead source**. Values should exactly match the lead source values on the lead.
2. Create a flow that looks up the campaigns where the new **lead source** field is not null
3. Loop through the leads and assign the ids based on the campaign with the matching lead source

As I imagine this in a flow (I don't work with them often so there may be some optimizations) it seems that it would run very inefficiently. I'm sure it can be done but I think using apex code in a trigger would allow for something that operates much more efficiently.

**The key take away here is that by having matching fields from 1 record to the other, you can get rid of all of the extra nodes.**

In Apex I'd use a map:

Map sourceToCampaign = new Map();

```
for (Campaign c : [
    SELECT Id, LeadSource__c
    FROM Campaign
    WHERE LeadSource__c != null
]) {
    sourceToCampaign.put(c.LeadSource__c, c);
}

for (Lead l : leads) {
    l.campaignId = sourceToCampaign.get(l.LeadSource);
}
```

Comment: In the visual flow, when you do a Fast Lookup for campaigns, you can create a lookup criteria where Campaign.lead_source contains lead.leadsource. This way you only have to loop through the campaigns that are relevant.